# Rails 4 - Paperclip - Dropbox production issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropbox

I'm using the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), [paperclip-dropbox gem](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox), [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro), and Dropbox to upload and store images when a product is created. Locally, in development, the image file is uploaded to the database fine, and is visible, but in production, where the image is supposed to go to Dropbox, the form doesn't go through, and I get a Dropbox Authentication error when looking at my Heroku logs. I've triple checked that my Dropbox security keys are all correct. I've looked through all related questions, and I can't find anything that will work.

Here is the error from heroku:

```
 DropboxAuthError (User is not authenticated.):
2014-07-12T16:04:12.514637+00:00 app[web.1]:       app/controllers/products_controller.rb:31:in `block in create'
2014-07-12T16:04:12.514638+00:00 app[web.1]:       app/controllers/products_controller.rb:30:in `create'
2014-07-12T16:04:12.514640+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-12T16:04:12.514642+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-12T16:04:12.512474+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2361ms
```

**Here is my products_controller #create action:**

```
 # POST /products
 # POST /products.json
 def create
 @product = Product.new(product_params)
 @product.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { 
      redirect_to @product,
       notice: 'Product was successfully created.'
        }
    format.json { 
      render json: @product,
       status: :created,
        location: @product 
      }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { 
      render json: @product.errors,
       status: :unprocessable_entity
   }
   end
 end
end
```

**Here is the params at the end of products_create:**

```
 private

 def set_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 end


 def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:description, :name, :permalink, :price, :file,  :user_id)
 end
```

**Here is my product model:**

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 if Rails.env.development?
    has_attached_file :file
 else
    has_attached_file :file,
    :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
    :path => ":style/:id_:filename"
 end


 belongs_to :user
 has_many :sales

 validates_numericality_of :price,
    greater_than: 49,
    message: "must be at least 50 cents"

 validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg     image/png)

end
```

**And finally here is the form for creating a new product:**

```
 <%= form_for(@product,:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
 <% if @product.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from  being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :permalink %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :permalink %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :price %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :file %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget the very important step of telling Heroku about the Figaro gem when using this method.

```
 rake figaro:heroku
```

did the trick for me. Looking at the [gem page now](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro), I'm not seeing that command, but there is a  section dedicated to deploying to Heroku to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I ended up having to change the environment in the conditional from development to production.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  if Rails.env.production?
    has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg",
    :storage => :dropbox,
    :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
:path => ":style/:id_:filename"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
  else
    has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "default.jpg"
  end
end
```

I don't know why it doesn't work when development is specified instead of production, but at least the latter works.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to answer but it may help someone.

In Dropbox's developers console, changing the `'Development user'` setting works.
Initially when an app is created, `'Development users'` will be `'Only you'`.

So click 'Enable additional users' button which allows more user to access the app.